# Domain in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, indexing, subdirectory

I have two separate pages and the page that is in subdirectory is not indexed as expected. When I google it, its saying `www.page1.com/page2`, where `page1` is in root directory, and `page2` is in folder `page2`, but when i enter `www.page2.com` the domain is working great. I suspect that the `htaccess` is the problem. Anyone with ideas?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site2/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site2/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `Settings->General` menu. There you can define `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`, which in my case were different because my development was in localhost and problem occurs when I transfer the solution in production.